# Android timer with two buttons start/break and reset and minutes:seconds

Tags: android, timer, format, stopwatch

I want to create a Timer which displayes only minutes and seconds in the format = 00:00 and two buttons, one for start and break and a second for reset. I started with a tutorial from: [StopWatch Tutorial](http://androidituts.com/android-stopwatch-tutorial/)

Then I added a thrid button. But now I didn´t know how to change the java file. I thought of a if/when loop but don´t know how to start this.

Here is my MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    /** Für die Stoppuhr generierte Variablen */
    TextView textTimer;
    Button startButton;
    Button pauseButton;
    Button resetButton;
    long startTime = 0L;
    Handler myHandler = new Handler();
    long timeInMillies = 0L;
    long timeSwap = 0L;
    long finalTime = 0L;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textTimer);

        startButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);
        startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                myHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerMethod, 0);
            }
        });

        pauseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPause);
        pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                timeSwap += timeInMillies;
                myHandler.removeCallbacks(updateTimerMethod);
            }
        });

        resetButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnReset);
        resetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finalTime = 0;
                timeInMillies = 0L;
                timeSwap = 0L;
                textTimer.setText("00:00");
            }
        });


    }

        private Runnable updateTimerMethod = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                timeInMillies = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;
                finalTime = timeSwap + timeInMillies;

                int seconds = (int) (finalTime / 1000);
                int minutes = seconds / 60;
                seconds = seconds % 60;
                int milliseconds = (int) (finalTime % 1000);
                textTimer.setText("" + minutes + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds) + ":" + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
                myHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Could please help me?

Comment: are the start/stop buttons working and what the third button should do?

Comment: what the third button will do?

Comment: up to now i implement three buttons:
1. Start timer
2. Pause timer
3. Reset timer
this I only did to see how it works.

But what I want in the end, is only two buttons:

1. Start timer (with the first click) and Pause timer (with the second click)
2. Reset timer